# How do i convert following loop into an SQL statement to run on a MySQL database

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to select rows from a database but with a condition that the next row will have its timestamp 5-10 min greater(I am saving my timestamp as long using a Java conversion) and the data should be collected from within a range of timestamps

E.g I have 4700 rows between timestamp 1434758400 and 1434412800
I need to reduce the number of rows, so what I was trying to do is selecting row which has 5-10-15 min of interval in timestamp

It is easy to write in a for loop as follows:

```
for(int i=1434412800 ;i<=1434758400 ;i=i+900) //INTERVAL OF 15 MIN
{
    select();
}
```

But I know I cannot use this as SQL statement ...
How can this be converted into a SQL statement?

Comment: If you could do it in a loop, what would the query look like?

Comment: You said it's easy to write in a loop.

Comment: ya but i don't know how to use that loop in sql statement

Comment: just show us your best effort - even if you know it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE (FLOOR(unix_timestamp(timestampField) / 900) - FLOOR(1434412800 / 900) = :i)
```

But here I use `i++` instead of `i+=900`, I mean `i = 0` will give rows for first page `[1434412800, 1434412800 + 900)` and `i = 1` for second page `[1434412800 + 900, 1434412800 + 1800)` and so on.

Comment: Same error. I am using phpMyAdmin on mac via MAMP is that ok with all these statements??